# javaのScannerクラスについての質問です。

Tags: java

下記の様なコードを作成しました。
このプログラムを実行すると、classファイル実行時にエラーが出ます。
どうやらScannerクラスのcloseメソッドに問題があるようです。

以上のことを踏まえた上で質問させていただきます。
Scannerクラスでsc1とsc2の様に呼び出した後、 `sc1.close()` などとしてcloseメソッドを呼び出したら、sc2の標準入力ストリームも閉じてしまうのでしょうか？

別々のものとして呼び出しているはずなのに、この様な事が起こる事がとても不思議です。

ご回答のほど、どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

**エラーメッセージ:**

```
mainメソッド内の入力(1) > 1
メソッド呼出しの入力 > 2
mainメソッド内の入力(2) > Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:945)
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1602)
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2267)
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2221)
        at Test.main(Test.java:11)
```

**現状のコード:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.print("mainメソッド内の入力(1) > ") ;  int a = sc1.nextInt() ;
       
        processInput();
        
        System.out.print("mainメソッド内の入力(2) > ") ; int b = sc1.nextInt() ;
        
        sc1.close();
        
    }
    
    static void processInput() {
        Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(System.in) ; 
        
        System.out.print("メソッドでの呼出しの入力 > ") ; int input = sc2.nextInt() ;
        
        sc2.close();
      
    }
    
}
```

Comment: "closeメソッドを呼び出したら、sc2の標準入力ストリームも閉じてしまうのでしょうか？" その通りのようです。[NoSuchElementException Scanner で検索](https://www.bing.com/search?q=NoSuchElementException+Scanner&qs=n&form=QBRE&sp=-1&ghc=1&lq=0&pq=nosuchelementexception+scanner&sc=10-30&sk=&cvid=01EF4FA30AE8434198B45A7C64D350B3&ghsh=0&ghacc=0&ghpl=)すると出てくる以下のページで詳しく解説されてます。 [標準入力のScannerを1度closeしたら、2度と標準入力できない理由を調べた \- Qiita](https://qiita.com/BinomialSheep/items/97d79e18faa3a2ba80de)

Comment: ところで質問文ですが、おそらく「なぜclose()すると別のScannerインスタンスも閉じてしまうのか」を聞きたいのだと思いますが、「close()を呼び出すと別のScannerインスタンスも閉じてしまうからエラーが発生するのか、どうすれば解決できるか」を聞きたいのかがやや不明瞭なためそこをわかりやすく書き直した方がいいと思います。

Answer (score 0):

> `sc1.close()` などとしてcloseメソッドを呼び出したら、sc2の標準入力ストリームも閉じてしまうのでしょうか？

その文は正しいですが質問文のコードで起きているのは逆で、「`processInput()` 内で `sc2.close()` をしたため `System.in` がクローズされ、`sc1` がデータを取れなくなった」です。

1つのストリームから複数の`Scanner`インスタンスを作るべきではありません。`processInput()` に `Scanner` 引数を足して `sc1` を渡して使うべきです。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in) ; で生成した分だけ、標準入力ストリームが生成されると勘違いしていたのですね。